# How do I get mdadm to send its emails via msmtp?

Tags: mdadm, msmtp

I recently upgraded one of my systems to Debian Buster, and now I cannot get mdadm to send out its email messages.  Previously I had ssmtp configured, and it worked just great, but it is no longer maintained.  I tried, but was unable to get exim4 working, so I chose to install msmtp and msmtp-mta.  I can readily send an email from the system using the msmtp command, but when mdadm attempts to send a message, sendmail complains the server is rejecting it because the mailbox is not found.

Comment: Check what mailbox msmtp is being told to send to, according to its logs.

Comment: Msmtp is not writing anything to any log when mdadm is invoked by the command:

Comment: mdadm --monitor --scan --test -1  The text "sendmail: cannot send message: Malformed email address" is sent to stderr when the command is invoked.

Comment: Also note attempting to send a message using sendmail fails, but again with no logs.

Answer (score 2):

```
I believe I have fixed the problem.  For anyone else who runs across this:
```

1. Add both the following lines into /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

```
MAILADDR <recipient>
MAILFROM <sender>
```

2. Create a symlink in /usr/sbin

```
cd /usr/sbin
ln -s ../bin/msmtp sendmail
```

```
Installing msmtp-mta is supposed to handle #2, but for whatever reason did not do so.
```